# can I open chart wizard in runtime c# application like excel chart wizard?

Tags: c#, charts, wizard

I am building c# application and I used chart control in it,but I wondered if I can open chart wizard in runtime , I found a library (devexpress - xtrachat control) that enables me to do that ,but it is not free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt it.. But you can place form controls and plot the chart based on user selection. For eg. you can have check boxes for series and based on the check box selection of the user, you can plot the series.

Comment: thanks..I think that by using traditional chart control , I must build chart wizard manually